# TCL-REGEX:: How to filter a line that appears multiple times in a text file using TCL regexp

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

Input file (resultnew.txt):

```
www.maannews.net.

www.maannews.net.

 ################################################# 

attach2.mobile01.com.

www.google-analytics.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

www.google-analytics.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

www.google.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

attach2.mobile01.com.

 ################################################# 

cdn-img.mocospace.com

cdn-img.mocospace.com

www.mocospace.com.

cdn-img.mocospace.com

cdn-img.mocospace.com

cdn-img.mocospace.com

www.mocospace.com.

cdn-img.mocospace.com

www.mocospace.com.

www.google-analytics.

www.google-analytics.

fonts.gstatic.com.

cdn-img.mocospace.com

cdn-img.mocospace.com

fonts.gstatic.com.

fonts.gstatic.com.

 #################################################
```

My TCL Script:

```
set a [open resultnew.txt r]
set b [open balu_output.txt w]


while {[gets $a a1] >=0} {
    if {[regexp {[a-zA-Z\.]} $a1]} {
    puts $b $a1
    }
}
```

My Requirement:

1. From the above text file, I want to remove the lines that appears multiple times and want to print only one time into a new file.
2. Point 1 should happen between each "#################" and "#################". Still  "################# should appear in that text file".

Please help me with your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Balu P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you need distinct value between the comment line (i.e hashess...... ). Below is the solution which you are looking for ... basically in script array key is used to keep unique values and re-initializing the array whenever next divider line (i.e your hash comment line is seen )...

I printed values on the STDOUT you can redirect them to other file.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set a [open resultnew.txt r]

# set an array to keep the unique records
array set myarray {}

# For each line in the input
while {[gets $a a1] >= 0} {

    # Get rid of extra spaces
    set a1 [string trim $a1]

    # if divider line found then print it (i.e ####)
    if { [string match "#*" $a1] } {
      puts $a1
      # unset the array for next set of entries
      array unset myarray
    } else {
      # Ignore empty lines
      if {$a1 ne "" }  {
        # print only if doesnot exists in the array
        if { [info exists myarray($a1) ] } {
          set myarray($a1) 1 
        } else {
          puts $a1
          set myarray($a1) 1
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Output of the script using your input file

```
$tclsh main.tcl
www.maannews.net.
#################################################
attach2.mobile01.com.
www.google-analytics.
www.google.com.
#################################################
cdn-img.mocospace.com
www.mocospace.com.
www.google-analytics.
fonts.gstatic.com.
#################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a different way to check whether to ignore lines, and an array is *great* for doing the uniqueness check. Here's an annotated version:

```
# For each line in the input
while {[gets $a a1] >= 0} {
    # Get rid of extra spaces
    set a1 [string trim $a1]
    # Ignore empty and comment lines; [string match] is great for this!
    if {$a1 eq "" || [string match "#*" $a1]} {
        continue
    }
    # See if this is the first time we've seen a line
    if {[incr occurrences($a1)] == 1} {
        # It is! Print it now
        puts $b $a1
    }
}
```

If you have a horribly large file you might eventually run into problems with memory usage. But for files with (up to) just a few million lines, you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Donal fellows.. Thanks for your Answer. I am getting the following error when I run this script.                            C:\Users\test\Desktop\>tclsh grep_line.tcl
can't read "occurrences(www.maannews.net.)": no such variable
    (reading value of variable to increment)
    invoked from within
"incr occurrences($a1)"
    ("while" body line 9)
    invoked from within
"while {[gets $a a1] >= 0} {
    # Get rid of extra spaces
    set a1 [string trim $a1]
    # Ignore empty and comment lines; [string match] is great f..."
    (file "grep_line.tcl" line 10)

C:\Users\test\Desktop\>

Comment: For larger files, import the file into [tag:sqlite3].